# Can't open new tab or window with JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

Note that this is not for a live website; it's just some experimentation for my own enrichment. I'm running Chrome Version 35.0.1916.153 (latest) on Mac OSX 10.9.3.

As many others have tried to do, I'm trying to have JavaScript open a link in a new tab. There are a lot of examples out there, but I can't get any of them to work. The most promising idea seems to be to simulate a <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>click</kbd> on an anchor. The click event occurs, and the event object's `metaKey` property is set to `true`, as I can see when I add a click handler, but no URL is opened: no new window, no new tab.

HTML:

```
<a id="still" href="gv__.html?pictureMode=still" target="_blank">still</a>
<a id="motion" href="gv__.html?pictureMode=motion" target="_blank">motion</a>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var e = $.Event( "click", { metaKey: true } );
                                
    $("a#motion").trigger(e);
    $("a#still").trigger(e);
    $("a#motion").trigger(e);
    $("a#still").trigger(e);
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that browsers usually block your code when you try to open a new window/tab programatically.

So new tab/window openings always have to be triggered by user action. (Otherwise we'd always be full with popup ads)

So 1st of all, make sure that your js is executed on a user event, and then you should be able to use `window.open`.

## [JsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/albertmatyi/V9APL/)

### html:

```
<a href="//google.com" target="blank">new tab google</a>

<button class="user">user triggered</button>
<button class="programatic">programatic</button>
```

### js:

```
$('a').on('click', function(e) {
    console.log('clicked', e);
    // unfortunately although we simulated 
    // the click on the <a/> , it will still 
    // not launch a new window - idk why.
    // therefore we can use the line below
    // to open the <a>'s href in a new tab/window
    // NOTE: this will only occur if the execution was
    // triggered by the user
    window.open(e.currentTarget.href);
});

var simulateClick = function(origEv) {
    var e = $.Event("click");
    e.ctrlKey = true;
    e.metaKey = true;
    e.originalEvent = origEv;
    $('a').trigger(e);
};

$('button.user').on('click', function(e) {
    // this call will actually open a window
    simulateClick(e);
});

$('button.programatic').on('click', function(e) {
    // this will result in a blocked popup
    $.get('/someurl').always(function() {
        // executes the method after a non-user event
        // results in blocked popup
        simulateClick(e);
    });
});

// this will result in a blocked popup
setTimeout(simulateClick, 1000);
```

Comment: Very helpful and enlightening. Plus it looks like you did a lot of work to create the example--it would have been non-trivial for me, anyway. Thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var e = $.Event("click");
e.ctrlKey = true;
$("a#motion").trigger(e);
$("a#still").trigger(e);
$("a#motion").trigger(e);
$("a#still").trigger(e);
```